# Where can I download gd.h?

Tags: c, windows-vista

I'm using Dev C++ to write a simple C program and I need to create an image. I know how to use GD but unfortunately it's not included in Dev C++ installation.

Where can I download gd.h file? I'm using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gd.h alone won't work. You also need the library files to link against - try to use [the windows distribution for libgd](http://www.libgd.org/releases/gd-latest-win32.zip). I can't guarantee it will work with DevC++ though...

Comment: I bow to your more helpful and sensible answer :)

Answer (score 1):

seems to be part of libgd. I found lots of stuff about it on www.libgd.org .